# How to post an external url in your website

Tags: python, django, request, frontend

I am now to django and web programming.
I'm trying to make a practice site that shows the search result of another website. I use $requests$ to get the page and $Httpresponse$ to show the page result but the result page does not display the table an the images.
when I open the html with my browser there are

I don't want to use iframe because there is a button on the page that I do not like to appear in my page

```py
def index(request):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':  # If the form has been submitted...
         html=requests.get(url).text
          return HttpResponse(html)
```

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) info-small.png:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (index):63 Uncaught
>
> ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at (index):63 warning-32.png:1  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (index):2134
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at (index):2134 info-small.png:1  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You can use beautiful soup for web scrapping or Rest api.

Answer (score 0):

If you serve another website's HTML code from your own website, this will break local references to images, stylesheets, scripts and so on.

For instance, if the page `http://example.com/index.htm` includes the code

```
<img src="/img/logo.png" />
```

this refers to `http://example.com/img/logo.png`. If you include the same code but serve it under your own website at `http://my.website/page.htm`, this will be understood by the browser as pointing to `http://my.website/img/logo.png`, which does not exist.

Therefore, if you want to serve another website's HTML content, you need to adapt all the local paths to refer to the correct resources (either by serving them yourself or by pointing to the original absolute URI). You will likely run into other issues, so unless you have good reasons to go down this route, I would not recommend it.